# Upload failure in IE (SharePoint 2016)

Tags: sharepoint-server, iis, time-out, document-upload

I have odd issue in my environment. When I try to upload documents larger than 100MB to library using IE11 (32-bit) browser I get following error:

[image]

What is interesting, everything works fine when I switch to Firefox or Edge (I am able to upload files up to 2GB as this is the limit for web application). 
I suspected that there is some timeout on server side and therefore I have increased executionTimeout in web.config files. Unfortunately it didn't resolve my issue.
I am completely sure that configuration on SharePoint side regarding these limits is fine. I can confirm it by upload files through WebDAV as it works very well.

As we are using load balancer in this environment, I have modified hosts file on my client machine and entered direct address to my frontend server. When I flushed dns, upload started working fine on IE !!! (there is another WFE and the result was the same).

From my perspective, there is some issue on load balancer side which affects only IE11. I can observe following entries in Developer Tools console when I try to upload my files:

[image]

The second explanation would be some GPO for IE, but why would upload work when I modify hosts?

Did anyone encounter similar issues and could provide me some tips on how to fix upload on IE11?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you already have identified that the issue is with the Load Balancer probably best would be to check with the vendor of the LB solution.